# Objective C framework which serializes object trees into XML

Tags: objective-c, xml, object, serialization

I am searching a framework or library which serializes objects in Objective C into XML. There are libraries like WonderXML, but they only serialize properties with simple data types like string, int etc.
I consider big object trees with references to other objects. It is required that the library detects reference loops in this tree (this is not difficult). Can anyone provide some links or help for that problem?